# mmenu page always reverts to the top of page

Tags: mmenu

ive put in the standard mmenu but when i open the menu my page always goes to the top of the page, is there anyway to stop that when the menu is closed again you go back to the same place on the page.

any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but was able to fix it by simply removing

```
height:100%;
```

on my body and html css wrapper.

I changed my css from this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

to this:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

and it solved the issue for me.